# How to change host value for ansible while running using ansible-python module?

Tags: python-2.7, ansible, ansible-inventory

Here is my code, where I am passing value for host but it is executing command at localhost. I also tried passing hardcoded values and in output it's showing that it ran on that given host.
Here is the code :-

class defination and then,

```
def __init__(self):
    self.variable_manager = VariableManager()
    self.loader = DataLoader()
    self.inventory = Inventory(loader=self.loader, variable_manager=self.variable_manager, host_list="host")
    Options = namedtuple('Options', ['listtags', 'listtasks', 'listhosts', 'syntax', 'connection','module_path', 'forks', 'remote_user', 'private_key_file', 'ssh_common_args', 'ssh_extra_args', 'sftp_extra_args', 'scp_extra_args', 'become', 'become_method', 'become_user', 'verbosity', 'check'])
    self.options = Options(listtags=False, listtasks=False, listhosts=True, syntax=False, connection='local', module_path=None, forks=100, remote_user='ubuntu', private_key_file="/tmp/xxx-key2.pem", ssh_common_args=None, ssh_extra_args=None, sftp_extra_args=None, scp_extra_args=None, become=False, become_method=None, become_user='root', verbosity=None, check=False)

def execute_playbook(self, playbook, host, scriptname=None, command=None,
                     path=None, username=None, password=None, key=None):
    if not os.path.exists(playbook):
        print '[INFO] The playbook does not exist'
        sys.exit()

    script_path = None
    if scriptname is not None:
        script_path = os.getcwd() + '/' + scriptname
        if not os.path.exists(script_path):
            print '[INFO] The script does not exist'
            sys.exit()
    self.variable_manager.extra_vars = {'scriptname': script_path,
                        'host': host, 'command': command, 'path': path} # This can accomodate various other command line arguments.`
    passwords = {}
    if password is not None:
        self.loader.set_vault_password(password)
    play_source =  dict(
        name = "Ansible Play",
        hosts = host,
        gather_facts = 'no',
        tasks = [
            dict(action=dict(module='shell', args='sudo mkdir /tmp/test-ansible'), register='shell_out'),
            dict(action=dict(module='debug', args=dict(msg='{{shell_out.stdout}}')))
         ]
    )
    play = Play.load(play_source, self.variable_manager, self.loader)

    tqm = TaskQueueManager(
        inventory=self.inventory,
        variable_manager=self.variable_manager,
        loader=self.loader,
        options=self.options,
        passwords=passwords,
    )

    try:
        result = tqm.run(play)
    except Exception as e:
        print e, "Exception in Ansible tqm.run()"
```

Output is :-

```
PLAY [Ansible Play] *************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [command] ******************************************************************************************************************************
[WARNING]: Consider using 'become', 'become_method', and 'become_user' rather than running sudo

changed: [110.110.112.139]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [110.110.112.139] => {
"msg": ""
}
```

But it creates directory in my localhost not on "110.110.112.139".

Comment: Instead of play_source =  dict(
        name = "Ansible Play",
        hosts = host,
        gather_facts = 'no',
        tasks = [
            dict(action=dict(module='shell', args='sudo mkdir /tmp/test-ansible'), register='shell_out'),
            dict(action=dict(module='debug', args=dict(msg='{{shell_out.stdout}}')))
         ]
    ) if i am loading a playbook using DataLoader().load_from_file("playbook"), passing that to play but I am getting AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'upper'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set `connection='local'` as option inside `__init__`.
This means to Ansible that no matter what is the target host, execute tasks on localhost.

Don't set it (leave default) or use `ssh` to execute tasks remotely.

Answer (score 1):

```
def __init__(self):
    self.variable_manager = VariableManager()
    self.loader = DataLoader()
    self.inventory = Inventory(loader=self.loader, variable_manager=self.variable_manager, host_list="host")
    Options = namedtuple('Options', ['listtags', 'listtasks', 'listhosts', 'syntax', 'connection','module_path', 'forks', 'remote_user', 'private_key_file', 'ssh_common_args', 'ssh_extra_args', 'sftp_extra_args', 'scp_extra_args', 'become', 'become_method', 'become_user', 'verbosity', 'check'])
    self.options = Options(listtags=False,
                           listtasks=False,
                           listhosts=True,
                           syntax=False,
                           **connection='ssh'**, 
                           module_path=None,
                           forks=100, remote_user='ubuntu', 
                           private_key_file="/tmp/xxx-key2.pem", 
                           ssh_common_args=None,
                           ssh_extra_args=None,
                           sftp_extra_args=None,
                           scp_extra_args=None,
                           become=False,
                           become_method=None,
                           become_user='root', verbosity=None,
                           check=False
                   )
```